# In wordpress, one of the pages I can modify but it does not update

Tags: wordpress

No puedo actualizar una de las páginas. Se queda cargando y nunca termina. Las demás las hace rápidamente, excepto esa

Lo realicé varias veces

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.